# fastify route request and response handler type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, fastify

Anyone know what is the request and response handler type in fastify?

Now I am just using 'any', typescript eslint gave me a warning:

```
fastify.post('/ac', async(req: any , res: any) => {
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.

Comment: @Alvin can you try with tslint instead of eslint

Answer (score 18):

The appropriate types you're looking for are "FastifyRequest" and "FastifyReply", respectively.

They can be imported and implemented as shown below.

```
import { FastifyInstance, FastifyReply, FastifyRequest } from 'fastify';

fastify.post('/ac', async (req: FastifyRequest, res: FastifyReply) => {

});
```

Comment: When I try to access req.body.object, it prompted err at object - Property 'object' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)

Comment: https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/TypeScript/#request is helpful (the `type CustomRequest = FastifyRequest<{ Body: .. }>` part) for getting the req body typed

Comment: Updated url for above comment: https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/TypeScript/#request

Comment: why was this so hard to find??

Comment: It's still the wrong answer, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer should be to use an interface (eg. `IPostUser`) on `Body`, no need to create a whole custom request object, just do:

```
interface IPostUser {
  username: string
}

fastify.post('/:id', async (req: FastifyRequest<{ Params: { id: number }; Body: IPostUser }>, reply) => {
  console.log(req.params.id)
  console.log(req.body)
})
```

Or **even better**, you do *not* want to refine the types again in TypeScript if you also created a [Fastify JSON schema](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Validation-and-Serialization/). Yes, you really should use schemas!

In that case, you can better use [Type Providers in Fastify](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Type-Providers/), like the package `@fastify/type-provider-json-schema-to-ts`.